# Tree of Life in Text Format

Tags: database

Wondering if there is a [tree of life](http://tolweb.org/Eukaryotes/3) in Text format for open data sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not though the tree of life website, but the [Open Tree of Life](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/opentree/argus/opentree10.3@ott93302) exists to fulfil this need. You can export newicks of nodes which you are interested in.

Comment: I don't see how to export, would help if you wouldn't mind explaining.

Comment: @LancePollard if you look to the bar on the right hand side you should see a heading called "Download subtree as newick string". For large trees this will take you to the repository, but for smaller subtrees there should be an immediate tool.

Comment: Note that such a huge tree will be difficult for most treeviewers; [Dendroscope](http://dendroscope.org/) is probably a good bet

Answer (score 1):

The [NCBI taxonomy database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/taxonomy/) contains an (as far as I know most complete/up-to-date) database with information about all classified species.

I haven't tested it, but I would guess that its accessible through the [E-utilities tools](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/), which will usually allow you to query and download information in xml or raw-text format.

Additionally the whole data the taxonomy database is built on is available on the [NCBI ftp-server](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/taxonomy), they also include readme files so you can figure out how the data is formatted.